# R New Prediction with decision tree

Tags: r, decision-tree

I have this dataset:

```
"Density","bodyfat","Age","state"
1.0708,12.3,23,normal
1.0853,6.1,22,slim
1.0414,25.3,22,fat
1.0751,10.4,26,normal
```

I wrote this code:

```
library(rpart)

set.seed(1234)
ind <- sample(2,nrow(mydata),replace=TRUE, prob= c(0.7,0.3))
trainData <- mydata[ind==1,]
testData <- mydata[ind==2,]

myFormula <- state ~ bodyfat
albero <- rpart(state ~ bodyfat)

newdata <- data.frame(Density=1.0515,bodyfat=11.1,Age=24)
newdata

predict(albero,newdata,type="class")

print(albero)
```

This code not working and i obtain this 2 error:

```
albero <- rpart(state~bodyfat)
```

> Error in eval(expr,envir,enclos): object "state" not find

and:

```
predict(albero,newdata,type="class")
```

> Error in match.arg(type): 'arg' should be one of "responde","node","prob"

Comment: Probably just `alberto <- rpart(state~bodyfat, data=dat)` where dat is the name of your dataset.

Comment: you should read manual for the `rpart` package so you know what the functions therein require as input. however, in general, a model fitting function in R would require either a formula and `data = your_data` or `x` and `y` supplied directly.

Comment: ok, thanks now work. But if i insert bodyfat = 30 or bodyfat = 1 I obtain the same result: after "predict" : NORMAL. Why?